# How to do that blur at the end of horizontal flatlist?

Tags: react-native, styles

I'm building weather app and want to do this blur at the end of View of hour forecast, I've tried to use linear gradient, but I wasn't able to figure out, how to do that.

Thanks in advice :)

There is showed that blur, that I want to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaKS6.jpg

I've tried `react-native-linear-gradient`, but I didn't figure out, making that with this library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-native-svg to create such effect in my app.
Just use the LinearGradient to create a view with gradient fill of your blue with different stopOpacity values